# Start eclipse with no plugins?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, aptana

I installed the Aptana eclipse plugin and restarted and now my eclipse (Indigo) won't start up. As soon as I load it, it freezes - I waited for 15 min and tried several times and no success. I also tried starting up eclipse with the -clean command and same thing.

How do I startup eclipse with no plugins loaded? I'd like to be able to do that so I can get back in and hopefully uninstall the Aptana through the eclipse UI.

Thanks

Comment: Try increasing the memory settings of eclipse as described here http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Frunning_eclipse.htm.
Also check if there aren't any errors in your `<workspace_location>\.metadata\.log` file to find out what is causing the eclipse to freeze.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677369/disable-plugins-on-eclipse-startup