# Disable plugins on Eclipse startup

Tags: eclipse, plugins, startup, metrics

I just installed a plugin for Eclipse, but as a result Eclipse will no longer start. It says "There was an error" or some such uninformative message.

How can I start Eclipse without it loading plugins so that I can actually uninstall the offending software?

Comment: Specifying the exact error would always be helpful. What might seem to you an uninformative error might be a hint to someone else of the underlying problem.

Comment: Just for future Google-ability of this question, could you state the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Yeah it was "An error has occurred. See log file at...". I did look at the log file but it contained *so many errors* from many different plugins, it wasn't really any help. In the end my problem turned out to be the same as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810102/eclipse-juno-startup-error-log-file) and the solution given there worked.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As another person mentioned, you can try the -clean option. However, if it still fails to load and you need to revert your install, you should **NOT** simply delete a plugin on disk. If Eclipse thinks a plugin is there, and suddenly it's removed, you will run into all sorts of problems in the future.

The best approach is to use the Eclipse director (a managing application) to revert your install (this comes installed with Eclipse). You will need to know what previous revision you would like to revert to. You can see all the previous revisions of your Eclipse install in /p2/org.eclipse.p2.engine/profileRegistry/ where profile name is likely something like SDKProfile. In here you will see a number of profiles. Each one represents a previous state of your Eclipse install.  Find the revision you would like to revert to (they should all have a timestamp on them) and from the root of Eclipse execute the following command:

./eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -revert 1611571876423 -repository https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12

Obviously replace the revision with the one you want to revert too.  This says, please revert my Eclipse install to 1611571876423, and if you need any dependencies, look in  https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12 (Eclipse 4.18). If you're doing this for a different version of Eclipse, then change the URL as appropriate.

Comment: But it was close! Future readers: I had to delete the file at `YOUR_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap` and *then* run `eclipse -clean`. Solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810102/eclipse-juno-startup-error-log-file).

Comment: On macOS, the path to the Eclipse executable will look like the following: ~/eclipse/java-latest/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse

Answer (score 8):

Try to start eclipse with the `-clean` option.

Or try to <strike>delete</strike> move the pluings and the features.

Posting the error-message is more useful than "there was an error".
Look into the logfile or try to start from the console and post the error message here.

Edit: Irbull is right. Of course don't delete the files, just move them in another directory so you can move them back. His solution sounds very helpful and is even more professional.

Answer (score 6):

Check this image of the Eclipse Indigo Settings:

[image: Eclipse Indigo Settings]

Comment: You missed the part where Eclipse won't start.

Answer (score 2):

You can try moving the plugin from the plugins directory.  I don't think there is any "safe-mode" way to start Eclipse.

Once you can boot into Eclipse you can disable plugins individually by going to Help / About Eclipse / Installed software / Installation history
 and revert your installation.

Comment: Do not simply delete the plugin from the plugins/ directory. This will leave your Eclipse in a really unstable state. I'll post the proper way to revert your install.

Comment: Fair point.  You should move the plugins so you can undo any slip ups.  But assuming he knows the 3rd party plugin that is the culprit it should be safe to remove as long as it is not a core plugin.

Answer (score -1):

the first approach you should try is just to remove the related jars if you are pretty sure of what are supposed to be removed. I have tried this approach to remove a bunch of evil plugins which are hard to get rid of. Be sure to have a bak for those you are about to remove though